# User Attach Images To Post From Front End

Tags: front-end

Making a site that deals with custom parts. Id like to make it so when i make a post about a part i have a image upload button on that post in the frontend that lets users upload their custom pics to that post. The images would of course have to attach to that post. Looked over the search results here and on google and all i see is posting on front end with images. Nothing about letting users just attach data.

Comment: Sounds kind of like a comment in that regard. What about something like this? http://wordpress.org/plugins/comment-images/

Comment: No not at all what im trying to do. Thanks though. The site is http://terranbyte.com/asus-sabertooth-z77-lga-1155-intel-z77-hdmi-sata-6gbs-usb-3-0-atx-intel-motherboard/ and has you can see i have a image tab set up with the gallery of attached images. I want a form that lets users upload images and attaches them to the post so they will also show in that gallery.

Answer (score 0):

Try this example, [Allow Users To Submit Images To Your WordPress Site](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/allow-users-to-submit-images-your-site/) (http://wp.tutsplus.com)

You could implement by using the "Step 4 Define A Shortcode" method to display the upload function in any post or page.

Once the image is uploaded, you could register the image so it appears under "Uploaded to this post" under insert media from the "add media" button from a post or page.

Comment: Pretty good tutorial however being that it makes a custom post type for the images not really a way to link them to the posts. I guess you could but thats a ton of work. I guess there isnt a way to do this haha.